# Using "for" to insert colomns in the matrix

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, matrix

I have this program,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from random import *
n = 10
k = 10
for h in range (k):
    x[k] = [uniform(0, 10) for p in range(n)]
```

what I want is

```
for k = 1

X = np.column_stack((x[1]))
for k=2

X = np.column_stack((x[1],x[2]))
for k=3

X = np.column_stack((x[1],x[2],x[3]))
```

and so on
how can I do that in loop, please

Comment: If `x` is a list, then you can simply call `x[:k]` to get the first `k` elements.
I cannot come up with more code, since I don't understand exactly, what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

what do you want as output ? a 10x10 matrix filled with random number for numpy.random.uniform ?

in this case I would do that:

```
X=np.zeros(shape=[n,k],dtype='float')
for (x,y),value in np.ndenumerate(X):
    X[x,y]=uniform(0,10)
```

at least it's how I understand your code ...

Comment: An nxk matrix is indeed what he seems to want. But it can be done as simply as `np.random.uniform(0, 10, (n, k)`.

Comment: yes. I was too much thinking loop as he talked about loop ... but indeed your solution is way better.